# How do we pass the integer as an application argument? (Algorand, JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, algorand

I'm using the Algorand JS SDK.

Here, 10 corresponds to the amount I need to withdraw and In contract I am reading it as  Btoi(Txn.application_args[1])

but I'm getting the error `transaction XBDYB2GZCDKTDWHR2UU4BEPHACSTNBW5DDAROBL3RW3QY6PTWMHA: logic eval error: underflow on subtracting 12592 from sender amount 5000. Details: pc=119, opcodes=txna Assets 0 itxn_field XferAsset itxn_submit`

How can I pass an int?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode to uint 64.

Try this: `appArgs.push(algosdk.encodeUint64(10))`